# why cannot set property innerhtml of null showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why I cannot set property innerhtml of null showing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <script>
            var scr1 = 0;
            var scr2 = 0;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHtml= "Paragraph changed!";

document.getElementById("CS").innerHtml = "Your Score :"



function srt() {
 var a = document.getElementById("none");
     a.style.boxShadow = "none"
     setTimeout(function re(){
         a.style.boxShadow = "-4px -4px grey"
     },200)
}

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2 class="scr1" id="dome">Your Score :</h1>
    <h2 class="scr2" id="CS">Com Score :</h2>
    <br />
    <br />
    <center>
    <div class="mid"></div>
    <div class="srt" id="none">
        <h4>Start</h4>
    </div>
    </center>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Please help me with this code**

Inner HTML not working I can't find where is error so please help me

Comment: It is `innerHTML` not `innerHtml`. Also at the time of the assignment your DOM is not ready. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your code:

1. `innerHtml` isn't a property, you instead need to use `innerHTML`
2. You are trying to target elements in your js code before they are loaded on the page (the DOM - Document Object Model, isn't ready yet). To overcome this you can call your code when your page has loaded. You can do this by using `window.onload=init`, where `init` is a function, which runs when the page has loaded.
3. Your targeting the id `demo` in your javascript but you do not have an element with the id `demo` in your HTML, you have the id `dome` so I'm assuming `dome` is supposed to say `demo`

Fixing all of these things will fix your issue.

See a working example bellow:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script>
    function init() {

      var scr1 = 0;
      var scr2 = 0;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";

      document.getElementById("CS").innerHTML = "Your Score :";

      function srt() {
        var a = document.getElementById("none");
        a.style.boxShadow = "none";
        setTimeout(function re() {
          a.style.boxShadow = "-4px -4px grey";
        }, 200);
      }

    }
    
    window.onload = init;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 class="scr1" id="demo">Your Score :</h1>
    <h2 class="scr2" id="CS">Com Score :</h2>
    <br />
    <br />
    <center>
      <div class="mid"></div>
      <div class="srt" id="none">
        <h4>Start</h4>
      </div>
    </center>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your script tag to the bottom of page just below the body close tag .

Also you are referring to an element `"dome"`, but in html you have element `"demo"`, make them both the same

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>

</head>

<body>
  <h2 class="scr1" id="dome">Your Score :</h1>
    <h2 class="scr2" id="CS">Com Score :</h2>
    <br />
    <br />
    <center>
      <div class="mid"></div>
      <div class="srt" id="none">
        <h4>Start</h4>
      </div>
    </center>
    <script>
      var scr1 = 0;
      var scr2 = 0;
      document.getElementById("dome").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";

      document.getElementById("CS").innerHtml = "Your Score :"



      function srt() {
        var a = document.getElementById("none");
        a.style.boxShadow = "none"
        setTimeout(function re() {
          a.style.boxShadow = "-4px -4px grey"
        }, 200)
      }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```